# MVC Razor open a new link not opening

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using MVC4 , and in Razor engine I have a strongly typed view. I do have a lot of validation , but I figured that I could simply have a link open a newly spawned browser page, but this is not happening.

What could I be doing wrong?

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://fedgov.dnb.com/webform/displayHomePage.do">@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.duns)</a>
```

Edit:

Showing View Source code

```
<form action="/Account/Register" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="OeF9GVP__M0yxnCeShixsKBiT1OegJ3kS5BogaRW-rhSEGXkdMujjERy3dkIvf48UzllvLfi9bVFxGIljgq4ymi_uhZa1KlQX8yV2X3lazM1" />    <div class="box-content nopadding">



 <tr>
                        <td class="width30">
                            <a target="_new" href="http://fedgov.dnb.com/webform/displayHomePage.do"><label for="duns">DUNS #:</label></a>
                            <span class="tooltip-top helper" title="Click on labels to learn more about DUNS, CAGE, SIC and NAICS"><i class="icon-info-sign"></i></span>                
                        </td>
```

[image]

Clicking on the Link "DUNS" jumps to highlighting the validation required textbox, but doesn't display the numbers required text etc...   Seems a bit odd.

Comment: Can you ad the whole rendered HTML in its entirity? And, when you say its not happening... do you mean it opens in the same window? Or it doesnt travel to the link at all?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14509681/1844389

Comment: Any reason for having _new in your source code instead of _blank?

Comment: I think its the label thats causing issues, please see my answer.

Comment: Yes, it is the label for sure,  but i want it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe its caused by the label?

This (your original snippet) doesnt work for me...

```
<a target="_new" href="http://fedgov.dnb.com/webform/displayHomePage.do"><label for="duns">DUNS #:</label></a>
```

But this does...

```
<a target="_new" href="http://fedgov.dnb.com/webform/displayHomePage.do">DUNS #:</a>
```

EDIT: this also works for me...

```
<label for="duns"><a target="_new" href="http://fedgov.dnb.com/webform/displayHomePage.do">DUNS #:</a></label>
```

Comment: Interesting, looking... hang on

Comment: Maybe try getting the a tag inside the label tag... not really sure how the HTML spec deals with your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, I think this might helps you

```
<a href="http://fedgov.dnb.com/webform/displayHomePage.do" target="_blank">@Html.Raw(Html.LabelFor(m=>m.duns))</a>
```

Comment: Still doesn't open the link

Comment: Is that page is opening in a same tab or window ?

Comment: I will want it to open in a new windows, not a new tab,   so i'm going to want a _new  and not a _blank    but either way it is not working