# MVC button should open url in new window/tab

Tags: asp.net-mvc, button, target

It's not clear what the proper syntax should be, and i tried some examples already but with no luck, this is my current button code that working  and i need it to stay as a button when clicked open the action in new window/ new tab

```
<input type="button" title="Read" value="@T("Account.DownloadableProducts.Read")" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("GetDownload", "Download", new { orderItemId = Model.DownloadMappingIds[product.Id].guid })'" />
```

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do this using javascript function

```
 <input type="button" value="MyButton"  onclick="myfunction(this)" 
 data-myurl="@Url.Action("aa", "bb", new { id=@id})"  /> 


  <script>
   function myfunction(e)
     {
     var url = $(e).data('myurl');
     var popupWindow = window.open(url,title,'scrollbars=1,height=650,width=1050');
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Great. For the rest of us that don't know MVC so well, what are "aa", and "bb"?  You should have had something like @Url.Action("Read", "MyController", new { id=@id}) .  Sorry, just a pet peeve of mine that people assume we know stuff right off, instead of completing the example.

Comment: A variation on this:  this might be messier, but instead of the @Url.Action, you could just say something like `data-myurl="/OtherBranch/Index?id=@id"` and redirect to that within `myfunction()` with `var newUrl = window.location.href.split('/FirstBranch')[0] + e.attr('data-myurl');`

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with this for a while, the solution was to, instead of target="_blank", you should use formtarget="_blank".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling to read your question and code but to open new windows, the following code is used:

```
target = "_blank"
```

Is it possible to tidy your question up a bit and then I'll be able to assist you further.