# Anchor tag helper to open view in new window-tab

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

Using an [anchor tag helper](http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2015/06/01/mvc-6-anchor-tag-helper.aspx), how can we open an ASP.NET Core MVC `View` in a new browser window-tab. I tried the following but first it complained that `target` attribute need to have `href` attribute as well. But, as we know, we can't use the href attribute with `asp-action` attribute in `MVC Core`; otherwise we get the error shown below. **NOTE**: I've seen some suggestions like t[his one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14509681/1232087), but they are not tag helper related:

```
<a asp-action="testAction" href="#" target="_blank">Click Here</a>
```

**Error:**

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot override the 'href' attribute for
>   . An  with a specified 'href' must not have attributes starting
>   with 'asp-route-' or an 'asp-action', 'asp-controller', 'asp-area',
>   'asp-route', 'asp-protocol', 'asp-host', or 'asp-fragment' attribute.

Comment: If you ignored visual studio warning about the target attribute it still works.
You may remove href and keep target. Also close the anchor tag </a>.
Otherwise you can use  <a href="/TestAction" target="_blank">Click Here</a>
Another interesting solution is to add your custom tag helper. refer to this answer for more information https://forums.asp.net/t/2083444.aspx.

Comment: Please note, there is no MVC6 anymore, as it was renamed to avoid confusion. If you **keep** using it, you just increase confusion of other people.

Comment: @MohamedRozza Your suggestion of ignoring VS warning in this particular case worked. Thank you.

Comment: try just taking out the href but leave in target="_blank"

Comment: Documented at https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/1428 .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I’m not sure if you’re asking a question or if you’re sharing your findings?

As @Mohamed Rozza mentioned in the comments, if you **disregard** the Visual Studio warning about the `target` attribute only allowed when the `href` is present, then you’ll quickly realize that the hyperlink actually works and opens in a new tab. Regardless of Visual Studio complaining.

As you’ve also pointed out, there is an alternative/workaround where you could create your link like this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("testAction","Home")" target="_blank">Click Here</a>
```

But, as you’ve said, this approach is not tag helper related. But so what?

My questions are these:

- How important is it for you and your project to be 100% tag helper
  related?
- Is it a must?
- Is it a show-stopper if you don’t always use tag helpers?
- Can you live with workarounds?
- Can you live with Visual Studio showing you a warning?

You have two working example that achieves your task.

1. One by disregarding the VS warning
2. The other by using a workaround using the Url.Action()

None of these two approaches are bad/wrong. If for some reason you feel compelled to write your own custom tag helper to overcome this...then by all means, go ahead!

If you wish to report a bug to Microsoft about the tag helper not supporting the target attribute without the href, then by all means go ahead!

And finally, if I do not understand the need to be 100% tag helper related (or if I’m over simplifying stuff) then by all means, feel free to share as we may offer a better alternative.