How to open URL in new tab on C# ASP.NET Core MVC
I've tried ScriptManager but the System.Web.Extension is not available to add on project references. So I'm asking for another way to call URL and open it in a new tab. I know response.redirect calls URL but I don't know how to redirect it to the new tab.
Thank you for anyone who address my concern. There is no button, once the page is called, it will do some code behind and redirects to a page.
var xURL = "www.google.com";

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType, "NewWindow", "window.open('" + xURL + "');", True);
       
Response.Redirect(xURL);


See this answer (I think it is the most direct): https://stackoverflow.com/a/14509663/1467914 ... or review other answers to the same question. I think if you google aspnetcore open view in new window you will see many similar solutions. This idea of using a ScriptManager seems to go back 20 years ... I'm not sure where you got that from but its not an up to date solution and not really part of aspnetcore anymore so far as I know - unless there is some misunderstanding about what you are working with here.

This approach is flawed.  Response.Redirect is a server-side method.  Opening a new tab is client-side, not server side.
Your code doesn't give any context, but if you are running within an MVC controller, you could return a view.  The view could contain a Javascript snippet to execute window.open on the client side, with the correct parameters to open a new tab.
In any case, Response.Redirect is not going to give you what you're looking for.

So on the server side, there's no way to call URL in a new tab? I need to have UI to make it work?

If you are making an AJAX call or your application is a web service, you could return a Javascript object that contains the URL you want to redirect to.  But if you are sending any other GET or POST from an HTML page, you have to send back HTML with an embedded script containing window.open.  The back end can only control such browser behavior via HTML.

"ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript" is for webform which is not supported in Asp.Net core. But you could try a little trick to run javascript from controller.
HomeController
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(string? nothing)
        {
            var xURL = "https://www.google.com";
            string script = $"window.open('{xURL}', '_blank');";
            // Pass the JavaScript to the view using ViewBag or ViewData
            ViewBag.CustomScript = script;
            return View();
        }

Index.cshtml
<form asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Home" method="post">
    <button type="submit">Open new tab</button>
</form>
<script>
    @Html.Raw(ViewBag.CustomScript)
</script>

